# Repeating certain elements on new pages in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm pretty new with SSRS and I'm looking for a way to implement the following. I'm having a table that is expected to be rendered in multiple pages and I need to repeat an element in the report with every new page as in the shown image.

For example, if the table takes more than one page, what I need to do is to repeat the image in red and hide the image in green in the new pages.

I tried creating a subreport and adding those element to the headers but that didn't work. Obviously, the subreports headers and footers aren't rendered in the master report.

[image: Report sample]

Answer (score 1):

No need for subreport. Add a page header to your report (Report menu -> Add Page Header), and move the red box into the page header. In the body of the report put the green box, and then tablix/table. It should look similar to this in the design view:

[image: OP Image plus header]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that's not an option. There is already a page header in the report and that red box can't be shown on all pages. It should only show on that table's section.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify your requirements: What defines "that table's section?" Do you know the page numbers that this box should appear on? My hunch is that the cleanest answer will involve the page header, a visibility formula and possibly embedded code.

Comment: What I mean by table's section is the set of pages that contain the table. Also I don't know the page number of that box. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added a variable then insert code in Report Properties:

```
Public Function IsFirstPage(resident as string, currentResident as Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable) as Boolean
    If (resident<>currentResident.Value) Then
        currentResident.Value = resident
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Then add Expression to Hidden element (your case is the image in green):

```
=IIf(Code.IsFirstPage(Fields!szFirstName.Value+Fields!szLastName.Value, Variables!currentResident), False, True)
```